# ng-switch inside ng-repeat what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I have a page that is using my ClientController and template to show a table of information that is retrieved from the server. For each collection of data I'd like to have 2 table rows, one that is always showing, and another which only shows when the first one is clicked.

I've simplified the code as there is a bit more going on here, but nothing that I would have thought would affect this.

My HTML looks like

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="session in sessions" ng-switch on="sessionID">
    <tr>
      <td>{{session.test_name}}</td>
      <td><a ng-click="showID(session.session_id)">view {{session.session_id}}</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pop-open" ng-switch-when="session.sessionID">
      <td colspan="2">
        {{session.session_ID}} and more details
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in my controllers.js i have

```
.controller('ClientController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.showID = function(sessionID){
    $scope.sessionID = sessionID
    alert($scope.sessionID)
  }
}])
```

the alert pops-up with correct ID but the table rows aren't showing as I would have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually dont need ng-switch for this simple use case scenario, add variable like showDetails on session, that should do it...

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="session in sessions">
    <tr>
      <td>{{session.test_name}}</td>
      <td><a ng-click="session.showDetails = !session.showDetails">view details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pop-open" ng-show="session.showDetails">
      <td colspan="2">
        {{session.session_ID}} and more details
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**TO KEEP ONLY ONE OPEN AT A TIME**

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="session in sessions">
    <tr>
      <td>{{session.test_name}}</td>
      <td><a ng-click="showDetailsOfId = session.session_id">view details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pop-open" ng-show="showDetailsOfId == session.session_id">
      <td colspan="2">
        {{session.session_ID}} and more details
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks @HarishR this works but doesn't provide the full solution - the details shown will be pretty substantial so I'd like to open only one at a time which is why I wanted to use ng-switch.

Comment: in that case maintain a variable on $scope rather than on session.. check the updated anwer

Comment: that'll work - thanks - next time I'll think before I answer!